# Finding the equations of surfaces of revolution

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

I have the following question:

$$\text{Sketch and find the equations of the surfaces formed by}$$
$$\text{i) }x^2 - y^2 + 1 = 0 \text{ about the y-axis}$$ 
$$\text{ii) }x^2 - 2y^2 + 2a^2 = 0 \text{ about the x-axis}$$

What's a general method to answer these kinds of questions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For revolution of the curve
$$\text{i) }x^2 - y^2 + 1 = 0 \text{ about the y-axis}$$

You may express 
$$x(y)=\sqrt{1-y^2}$$
then
$$X(y,\phi)=\sqrt{1-y^2}\cos\phi$$
$$Y(y,\phi)=\sqrt{1-y^2}\sin\phi$$

Will be the equation for the surface formed by revolution.
Notice that $X(y,0)=x(y)$.

For revolution of the curve
$$\text{ii) }x^2 - 2y^2 + 2a^2 = 0 \text{ about the x-axis}$$
You may express 
$$y(x)=\sqrt{a^2+(x^2)/2}$$
then
$$X(x,\phi)=\sqrt{a^2+(x^2)/2}\sin\phi$$
$$Y(x,\phi)=\sqrt{a^2+(x^2)/2}\cos\phi$$

Will be the equation for the surface formed by revolution.
Notice that $Y(x,0)=y(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the equation $x^2-y^2+1=0$, you can simply put $x^2+z^2$ instead of $x^2$ to get
$$x^2+z^2-y^2+1=0.$$
The reason is that $r^2=x^2+z^2$ expresses the distance $r$ between a point and the $y$-axis. When a point is rotated around $y$-axis, the distance of the point from the axis remains unchanged.